# Showing different menus using media queries and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a hamburger menu for smaller screens. I have it working for small screens but if the menu isn't open prior to making the screen larger the menu doesn't show at all. If the screen is larger and I refresh the page the menu will show. I'd like the menu to switch in real time if the screen reaches a media query breakpoint. Just to be clear, I'd like the full menu to show on larger screens.

I'm using JQuery to show/hide the menu.

https://jsfiddle.net/fabfivefebby/87rywxxv/

```
var $hamburger = $('<button id="hamburger">&#9776;</button>');

$("header").append($hamburger);


// 2. toggle nav with icon

if ($("#hamburger").css("display") === "block") {

$("#nav_container").hide();

$hamburger.click(function(){

$("#nav_container").slideToggle("slow");
});

} else {
$("#nav_container").show();
}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have the hamburger menu showing by default (mobile first) and the nav_container hidden. I have the button in the markup. You don't really need to append it dynamically. Your media query can detect when it is larger (I set it to 481px) and hide the hamburger and show the nav_container. Your jQuery only needs to toggle the slide. I put '!important' on the media query nav_container display so that if it was hidden by the jQuery and you expand to larger display, it won't open since it's inline. Instead of using '!important', you can use CSS to hide/show the nav_container with classes.

https://jsfiddle.net/wilchow/8pmLf8sn/7/

css:

```
#hamburger {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 90%;
    background-color: #FFFFF2;
}
#nav_container {
    display: none;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding-top: 30px;
    background-color: #FFFFF2;
}
#navbar li {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
#navbar {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 100vw;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    #hamburger {
        display: none;
    }
    #nav_container {
        display: block!important;
    }
}
```